# Approximation of a definite integral using random numbers

Tags: definite-integrals, monte-carlo

I've read in my textbook that the Monte Carlo method (or random numbers) can be used to approximate a definite integral. If we select the first $n$ elements $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ from a random sequence in the interval $(0,1)$, then

$$\int_0^1{f(x)dx}\approx\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{i=1}f(x_i)$$

Here, the integral is approximated by the average of $n$ numbers $f(x_1), f(x_2), \ldots, f(x_n)$.

However, I don't exactly understand this. What I remember from my Calculus course is that the definite integral of a function is basically the area below the function. On the left-hand side, however, I see we're calculating the *average* of the evaluations of the function. We're summing up all the evaluations and then divide by $n$. How does this compare to the actual area under the function?

Any hints?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_a_function

Comment: Thank you, then why do textbooks explain integrals by using areas?

Comment: That's because the integral measures the area under the curve indeed. But it is also used to define the mean of a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The average of a function on an interval $[a,b]$ is
$$\frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f(x) \ dx$$

but here $b-a=1$. So $ \int_0^1 f(x) \ dx$ is indeed the average of $f$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Merci. I understood this part, but I don't know why many textbooks explain definite integrals as the area below the function. Is the average of $f$ on $[0,1]$ equal to the area below $f$ in the same interval?

Comment: What would be the height of a rectangle such that its width is equal to $b-a$ and its area equal to $\int_a^b f(x) \ dx$? Answer: the mean of the integral. you can also "see" that the area below the function is equal to the integral by splitting the area in small vertical rectangles, which is the Riemann integral.